# JavaFX 2.0 AudioClip doesn't play in applets?

Tags: java, applet, audio, javafx-2

Okay,so I made a small game in JavaFX 2.0, and I have a player shot sound which plays each time the player shoots. Works great on desktop, but doesn't play on applet.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why the shot sound doesn't play in the applet?

Here is the directory with the game. galaxy.html is used to play the applet.
[click here to go to game directory](http://www.prime.programming-designs.com/galaxy/)

And here is the code to load the audioclip:

```
playerShot = new AudioClip(Galaxy.class.getClassLoader().getResource("playershot.mp3").toString());
```

Comment: Where is the MP3?  Is it in [Galaxy.jar](http://www.prime.programming-designs.com/galaxy/Galaxy.jar)?  That is the only place it could be (at the root of that Jar) that it might me found.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the root of the .jar.

Comment: Have you also tried something like _Galaxy.class.getResource("/playershot.mp3").toURI().toString()_ ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with short MP3 audio In JavaFX 2.0.1. A workaround is to convert it to WAV or AIFF. For viewing the issue see http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-13945.